# Does Axure work in Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

Does Axure RP Pro6.5 works on an Ubuntu 11.04 machine? If yes what is the procedure to install it properly?

Comment: Note that a decent bit of Windows programs run under `wine` or `mono` (for .NET stuff).  Note though that *most* Windows commercial software does ***NOT*** have a Linux version, and note that compatibility with wine is *not* guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Axure doesn't have Linux version, but you can try to install it under `wine`.

I would like to mention that I tried it using Wine. it gets installed but unable to run.

Comment: Perhaps you should try it under Virtualbox as well...

Comment: Yeah, the Wine appdb information on it is [not too encouraging](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=vendor&iId=3974&sAction=view&sTitle=View+Developer).

Comment: The above answer is correct. As far as I know you can run Axure with version earlier than 5.6 under Wine because it is based on .NET framework 2.0. While versions after that is based on .NET framework 4 which the Wine currently doesn´t support.